How to apply a color filter to an Async image in Swift UI?
I can't work out how to dynamically filter (color filter) images that are being loaded. Eg I want to dynamically increase the saturation.
Filtering an image in SwiftUI looks straight forward using [CI library] (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/basic-image-filtering-using-core-image).
But I cant work out how to get a Core Image object from Async Image to be manipulated.
I would imagine it working something like this:
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/icon.png")) { image in
    Image(uiImage: myFilter(image.uiImage.ciImage).uiImage).resizable()
} placeholder: {
    ProgressView()
}
.frame(width: 50, height: 50)

Or maybe Image could be extended?

Did you have a look at public func colorEffect(_)?

colorEffect also seems viable but it turns out that the SwiftUI view modifiers recommended by @Sweeper were enough

AsyncImage can't give you a UIImage, but it is relatively easy to write your own AsyncImage that gives you a UIImage.
struct AsyncUIImage<Content: View, Placeholder: View>: View {
    let url: URL
    let contentBuilder: (UIImage) -> Content
    let placeholder: Placeholder
    
    @State private var content: Content?
    
    init(url: URL, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (UIImage) -> Content, @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Placeholder) {
        self.url = url
        self.contentBuilder = content
        self.placeholder = placeholder()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let content {
            content
        } else {
            placeholder
                .task {
                    do {
                        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                        if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                            content = contentBuilder(uiImage)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

Example usage:
var body: some View {
    AsyncUIImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200")!) { uiImage in
        VStack {
            if let ciImage = CIImage(image: uiImage) {
                processImage(ciImage)
            }
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }
    } placeholder: {
        ProgressView()
    }

}

func processImage(_ ciImage: CIImage) -> Image? {
    let context = CIContext()
    let filter = CIFilter.sepiaTone()
    filter.inputImage = ciImage
    filter.intensity = 1
    guard let output = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else { return nil }
    return Image(uiImage: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage))
}

Also note that the effects of some CIFilters can be achieved using SwiftUI view modifiers, such as blur, colorInvert, hueRotation, etc. For these filters, you can just apply them to the Image produced by AsyncImage.

The swiftUI View modifiers were enough in the end thanks for the recommendation. They can't edit the white point but you can get pretty far with them. This answer is also correct for if you need more advanced filters, in my case I didn't.
